# Login Control and Sql Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, login-control, sqlmembershipprovider

I'll trying to use the Sql Membership Provider with Login Control but the Login Control is creatting its own user, role, application.... tables but only used the user table...

I used aspnet_regsql for add tables and schema to my database to use Sql Membership

How can I configure Sql Membership for that the Login Control used the tables created by aspnet_regsql?

Below my web.config configuration for the providers:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="CrossReferenceWebSqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>

       <add name="CrossReferenceWebSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="CrossRef_DBConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, &#xD;&#xA; PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            applicationName="CrossReferenceWeb" />
    </providers>
 </membership>

<profile defaultProvider="CrossReferenceWebSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CrossReferenceWebSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="CrossRef_DBConnectionString" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
         applicationName="CrossReferenceWeb" />
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CrossReferenceWebSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="CrossRef_DBConnectionString" applicationName="CrossReferenceWeb"
      name="CrossReferenceWebSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aspnet_regsql` is deprecated. Please you use [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) which uses Entity Framework.

You do not need to do extra set up for Login control. Login will automatically pick up the setting which you configured in `Membership tag` in `web.config`.

Comment: Well, I'm tried to used ASP.NET Universal Providers but when I'm using the ASP.NET Configuration Tools is looking for the aspnet_regsql tables and stored procedured... Is posible solution that?

Comment: In your code, **roleManager** is still using old assembly. **type** should be `System.Web.Providers...`. Easiest way is - use **Package Manager Console**, and type `PM> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers`. Please refer to Scott Hanselman's article.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing in a blank project OpenAuth and Universal Provider but I read abot both but yet I don't sure wich is better... I'm using Web Forms with SQL procedures not Entity Framework.... which is better? and How can manage roles with this techonlogies?